# Jelly + JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, plugins, hudson, jelly

I'm working with [Hudson plugins](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Extend+Hudson). [Jelly](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/) views are the most complicated thing for me.

So the question is **how to use JavaScript code in Jelly scripts?**

P.S. "Hello World" script is working good but simple "for" loop brings a lot of problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are expecting but, to reference a javascript file (for example):

```
<script ... src="${rootURL}/plugin/findbugs/tabview-min.js" />
```

Regarding the "for" part, I don't get it exactly. Do you mean jelly's [`forEach`](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/tags.html#core:forEach)?

Comment: i mean something like this http://www.w3schools.com/JS/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_fornext

Answer (score 0):

For for loop jelly Gives error for < or > sign. Use array.forEach(FunctionName). Add logic for For loop in Function.